# Node/edge type definition in booggie for visualization with yEd?

Tags: graph, graph-visualization, booggie

In booggie 2, I can export graphs to yEd's graphML-Format. However, I've no clue how the node and edge type definitions in the metamodel should look like such that I can control their visual appearance

Could anyone please provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how a node type definition (has to be named **YEdNode**) with some yEd-attribute definitions looks like:

```
node class YEdNode{
    height: int = 50;
    width: int = 100;
    x: int = 0;
    y: int = 0;
    color : string = "#FFFFFF";
    shape : Shape = Shape::RECTANGLE;
    label : string = "";
}
```

And the same for an edge type definition (has to be named **YEdEdge**):

```
edge class YEdEdge{
    color : string = "#000000";
    lineWidth: int = 2;
    label : string ="";
    lineType : string = "line";
}
```

The shape-ENUM should look like that:

```
enum Shape {RECTANGLE, ROUNDRECTANGLE, ELLIPSE, PARALLELOGRAM, HEXAGON, TRIANGLE, RECTANGLE3D, OCTAGON, DIAMOND, TRAPEZOID, TRAPEZOID2}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. How is the shape-ENUM defined? Could you maybe add that to you example?